# bash script simple auto deployment with svn and phpunit

Tags: svn, phpunit, sh

I am trying to build simple deployment system with bash script. I have tried checking TeamCity and similar products, but they are too difficult and needs lots of time to understand configure ect. So my idea is to create bash script which:

1. connect to server using ssh
2. get current revision
3. svn update
4. run unit tests
5. if tests failed -> svn up -rXXX

What I have achieved:
I am running `sshpass -p 'pass' ssh user@IP "svn up; sh tests.sh";` which downloads commited changes to my server and runs all phpunit test.

The problem is that if my tests fail I need to revert chainges manually. I could get current revision using `svn info | grep "Revision" | awk '{print $2}'` and get bask to it, but I cannot find the way to check if tests failed in `tests.sh`. Anyone has any ideas how to achieve this? Or maybe you have better suggestions to achieve same results?

Comment: Why not testing it in another checkout, and upgrade the production version if the tests succeed to the revision number you just tested?

Comment: if you are using phpunit, you can check the exit code. If it's not zero, then something went wrong

Comment: @Wrikken I am not versioning configuration files so checkout would not work. And I do have dev test prod versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have built it using @gontrollez hint. `./deploy` script:

```
reset; 
sshpass -p 'pass' ssh dev@IP "./update";
RET=$?;
if [ $RET -eq 0 ];then
    sshpass -p 'pass' ssh test@IP "./update";
    RET=$?;
    if [ $RET -eq 0 ];then      
        sshpass -p 'pass' ssh prod@IP "./update";
        RET=$?;
        if [ $RET -eq 0 ];then      
            reset;
            echo "$(tput setaf 2)Success!"
        else
            echo "$(tput setaf 1)PROD test failed!"
        fi
    else
       echo "$(tput setaf 1)TEST test failed!"
    fi
else
   echo "$(tput setaf 1)DEV test failed!"
fi
echo "$(tput sgr0)"
```

`./update` script:

```
current=$(svn info | grep "Revision" | awk '{print $2}');
svn up;
sh tests.sh;
OUT=$?;
if [ $OUT -eq 0 ];then      
    echo "Update successful!"
else
    echo "Test failed! Reverting...";
    svn up -r$current;
    $(exit 10);
fi
```

And `tests.sh` runs phpunit tests